# select data from two collections mongodb

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb

We had two servers going, and some of the data went missing, so I need to check for what exactly IS missing and fix it.  An order's data looks like this:

```
 {
        "_id" : ObjectId("591a067bd7bc153c9bd4b5c2"),
        "customer" : "cus_AeMs19HKhEZDY7",
        "paymentID" : "ch_1AFb9pEz37oqk2rHVkbAfNrU",
        "paymentStatus" : "PAID",
        "user" : "melaniecarr23@gmail.com",
        "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-05-15T19:50:19.775Z"),
        "cart" : {
                "username" : "melaniecarr23@gmail.com",
                "totalQty" : 1,
                "totalPrice" : 50,
                "items" : [
                        {
                                "players" : [
                                        {
                                                "country" : "jlk",
                                                "zip" : "jkl",
                                                "state" : "jkl",
                                                "city" : "jkl",
                                                "address" : "jkl",
                                                "phone" : "432",
                                                "email" : "drmelaniecarr@gmail.com",
                                                "last" : "Snape",
                                                "first" : "Severus"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "adult" : null,
                                                "country" : "jlk",
                                                "zip" : "jlk",
                                                "state" : "jkl",
                                                "city" : "jkl",
                                                "address" : "jkl",
                                                "phone" : "432",
                                                "email" : "melaniecarr23@gmail.com",
                                                "last" : "Potter",
                                                "first" : "Harry"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "price" : 50,
                                "numplayers" : 2,
                                "group" : "nonpro",
                                "level" : "12s",
                                "division" : "Junior Boys",
                                "field" : "Main",
                                "day" : "Friday",
                                "event" : "Junior Boys 12s",
                                "id" : "58d89697ffc0346230a43a8d"
                        }
                ]
        },
        "__v" : 0
}
```

For each cart.item, there is a document in the registrations collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590aa7a13c85042478800c52"),
    "event" : "Women's B",
    "paymentId" : "ch_1AFb9pEz37oqk2rHVkbAfNrU",
    "createdOn" : ISODate("2017-05-13T06:24:07.609Z"),
    "paymentID" : "VOLUNTEER",
    "paymentStatus" : "PAID",
    "__v" : 1
```

}

I need to get a count of the items in the orders.cart.items array, and see if they match the number of results from registrations where paymentId is the same as the one in the order.
If they aren't the same, I need to see those results.

Can someone help me understand how to do this with mongo?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this one out, actually!  I had to use $lookup in the aggregation pipeline:

```
Order
  .aggregate([     
    {       $lookup:         
    {           from: "registrations",
                localField: "paymentID",           
                foreignField: "paymentId",           
                as: "REGISTRATIONS"         
    }    
    } 
  ]);
```

This allowed me to use ng-repeat and ng-if to display the lengths of the cart.items and REGISTRATIONS arrays and compare them.  If they were different, I displayed the contents of each.  It's EXACTLY what I was looking for, and was super quick!  Gotta love aggregation.